# Swift: unowned cannot be applied to non-class type THETYPE -> () -> THETYPE

Tags: swift

Open a new Swift project and add this to the ViewController.swift:

```
private lazy var imagePicker = {
    [unowned self] in
    let retval = UIImagePickerController()
    let selfDelegate = self as! protocol<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
    retval.delegate = selfDelegate
    retval.allowsEditing = true
    return retval
}()
```

*(We recast `self` with protocol conformance because protocol conformance is defined in class extensions for readability.)*

This produces two errors:

On the first line:

> 'unowned' cannot be applied to non-class type 'ViewController -> () -> ViewController'

and on the last line:

> Cannot invoke value of type '() -> _' with argument list ()'

Both of these errors make no sense to me. What do they mean and how can I fix them.

Comment: the 2nd error is probably cause by the missing type of the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the type of the variable:

```
private lazy var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController = {
```

That will fix both of your errors.

The compiler just got confused when trying to infer types. The closure is probably too complicated for it and all type-inferring problems end with strange error messages.

Comment: Thank you! Updated here https://github.com/fulldecent/FDTake/commit/d3c8a246a1ba971f6e7f247b49345a3875816f63